# Python - How to query a "s%d" whilst checking if %d is within list length?

Tags: python

I am reading a user input which must be a character and a integer within a limit.
Let's say I have a list 's' of size 3, then the user input must be "s%d" where %d must be 1, 2, or 3. The size can vary, so using:

choice == "s1" or choice == "s2" or ...
would not work.

Here is what I have:

```
num = [range(1, len(input) + 1)]
if choice == "s%d" %d in num:
  print("s%d)
```

I've tried a few options and python3 functions, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Let me know if I should provide more info.

** "s1" must be entered as a whole string, it cannot be separated.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: You should provide as much info to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the number from the user input is in your list len range, u can do:

```
num = [range(1, len(input) + 1)]
choice = input("Enter 's' followed by a number: ")
if int(choice[1:]) > len(l): # It will work if indeed the single
    <do something>           # letter is followed by an int.
```

Comment: s and the number must be together as one string. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Yes, I know. If user provides a string like "s532", `choice[1:]` will cut it to "532", so you can check later if `int("532")` is in range of list length.

Comment: if choice == "s" + str((choice[1:]) > len(num)):
   print(str(choice[1:]) > len(num))

I'd get a TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Comment: Lets say that the user typed "s53" and the list is `[1, 2, 3]`. Your code would evaluate to `if 's53' > 3` - and numbers cant be compared to strings. What you need, is the IF statement from my answer.

Comment: I understand, however, there are a few more other options besides "s53' which does something else. Therefore there is no liberty to ask:
choice = input("Enter 's' followed by a number: ")
I should've clarified, sorry for the trouble. I'm new to this...

Comment: You can always check if the choice starts with letter "s" and then if he is followed by a number in range of your list. `if choice.startswith('s') and int(choice[1:]) > len(num)`.